# Does supervisord ("supervisorctl start") wait for a command to finish, or fork it off asynchronously?

Tags: supervisord

I'm running supervisorctl start in a shell script and am wondering if I can count on that operation being finished by the time the next line in the shell runs. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot guarantee that supervisorctl start will finish what it's doing.

In fact, if you're running a web server, you should be very thankful that you cannot be sure that the web server has closed once supervisorctl start returns. :)